# Problema em Elemento com char e numero

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, javascript-eventos

não estou conseguindo fazer operações matemáticas com essa função, obviamente porque tem elementos tipo char dentro.

```js
var centesimas = 0;

function inicio() {
  control = setInterval(cronometro, 10);
  document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
}

function parar() {
  clearInterval(control);
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
}

function reinicio() {
  clearInterval(control);
  centesimas = 0;
  document.getElementById("Centesimas").innerHTML = "|00|"
  document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
}

function cronometro() {
  if (centesimas < 999) {
    centesimas++;
    if (centesimas < 10) {
      centesimas = "0" + centesimas
    }
    document.getElementById("Centesimas").innerHTML = ":" + centesimas;
  }
  if (centesimas == 999) {
    centesimas = -1;
  }
}

function resultado() {
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML += document.getElementById("Centesimas").firstChild.data * 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="contador">
  <div class="reloj" id="Centesimas">:00</div>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="inicio" value="&#9658;" onclick="inicio();">
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value="&#8718;" onclick="parar();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value="&#8634;" onclick="inicio();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value="&#8635;" onclick="reinicio();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="resultado" value="Resultado" onclick="resultado();">
  <div class="reloj" id="Result"></div>
</div>
```

ele sempre retorna NaN por conta disto, mas e gostaria de saber se tem como fazer sem remover os elementos tipo char de dentro

Comment: SUAVARIAVEL.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''); irá substituir caracteres não-numéricos.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código por completo? Parece que o mesmo veio sem algumas partes. Se possível, adicione o HTML também.

Comment: Opa, foi mal gente minha internet caiu, editei ae, esse código ja existe na internet, eu só modifiquei de acordo com algo que estou fazendo apenas para aprendizado, comecei a mexer com javascript tem nem 3 mêses

Comment: @edsonalves descupe, não faço ideia de como isso funciona :\ mas vou procurar sobre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o objetivo é apenas retornar o valor multiplicado por 3, você pode recuperar a `string`:

```
var cent = document.getElementById("Centesimas").firstChild.data;
```

Remover o caractere `:` com a função `slice`:

```
cent.slice(1); // Pega o conteúdo a partir do segundo caractere
```

E converter para um valor inteiro:

```
parseInt(cent.slice(1));
```

Assim, seu valor será inteiro e poderá fazer a multiplicação. Veja no código abaixo:

```js
var centesimas = 0;

function inicio() {
  control = setInterval(cronometro, 10);
  document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
}

function parar() {
  clearInterval(control);
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
}

function reinicio() {
  clearInterval(control);
  centesimas = 0;
  document.getElementById("Centesimas").innerHTML = "|00|"
  document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
}

function cronometro() {
  if (centesimas < 99) {
    centesimas++;
    if (centesimas < 10) {
      centesimas = "0" + centesimas
    }
    document.getElementById("Centesimas").innerHTML = ":" + centesimas;
  }
  if (centesimas == 99) {
    centesimas = -1;
  }
}

function resultado() {
  var cent = document.getElementById("Centesimas").firstChild.data;
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML += parseInt(cent.slice(1)) * 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="contador">
  <div class="reloj" id="Centesimas">:00</div>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="inicio" value="&#9658;" onclick="inicio();">
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value="&#8718;" onclick="parar();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value="&#8634;" onclick="inicio();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value="&#8635;" onclick="reinicio();" disabled>
  <input type="button" class="boton" id="resultado" value="Resultado" onclick="resultado();">
  <div class="reloj" id="Result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu, sua resposta foi bem útil é fácil, tenho dificuldade porque não sei quase nada de javascript

Comment: Excelente Anderson, muito bacano o uso "value="&#9658;" + type="button", para estes exemplos

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro eu aconselho sempre verificar se o tipo do elemento que vc vai trabalhar é um número:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n));
}
```

Se essa função retornar true, o valor de `n` é um número válido, se retornar `false` ai vc pode deletar o elemento.

Para remover os caracteres não numéricos de uma string utilize a seguinte regex:

```
value = value.replace(/[^\/\d]/g,'');
```

Comment: é um número, mas tbm tem carácter junto por isso não estou conseguindo fazer operação matemática com o elemento

Comment: Ah sim, me desculpe, complementei a resposta, utiliza a REGEX antes no valor que vc quer tirar as letras e depois verifica se é número, ai com ctz não vai dar erro.